# My app is rejected due to app has ads outside of the app

Tags: android, admob, ads

My app is rejected due to the claim that it has ads outside of the app. I thought that the interstitial ads are shown on pressing on home or recent or back buttons, then I removed all interstitial ads from my app then I submitted it again and unfortunately. It was rejected again for the same reason then I emailed the support and they answered that my app has ads outside of my app, I am really frustrated because my app does not really have any ads outside of the app, is any anybody face this problem before?

code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private AdView mAdView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    // initialize the Mobile Ads SDK
    MobileAds.initialize(this, getResources().getString(R.string.admob_app_id));

    // banners ads
    mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
    mAdView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            mAdView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }});
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    if (mAdView != null) {
        mAdView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mAdView.resume();
    }
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    if (mAdView != null) {
        mAdView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mAdView.pause();
    }
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    if (mAdView != null) {
        mAdView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mAdView.destroy();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
 }

 }
```

Comment: Please Share a screenshot of banner ads or native if you integrated

Comment: will screenshot help in solving the problem?